# Don't reload the view Django

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a set of questions, every question is answered with yes or no. Depends of answer will be other different question and this process would be repeat several times. The problem is that every time that the user sends the answer the view is reloaded and always show the first question.
I'm new in Django and web programming.
Thanks for your answers.

```
class ExpertoView(FormView):
    template_name = "SisExperto.html"
    form_class = FormExpert
    success_url = 'SisExperto'
    def __init__(self):
        self.arbol = eval(self.fileToStr('SisExperto/enfermedades.txt')) #evalua el archivo
        self.Nodoactual = self.arbol
        self.pregunta = self.Nodoactual[0]

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #This method is calle when valid for data has been POSTED
        #It should return an HttpResponse
        if len(self.Nodoactual) == 3:
            [self.pregunta, yesNode, noNode] = self.Nodoactual

            if form.is_valid(): 
                form_data = form.cleaned_data
                respuesta = form_data.get('campo')
                if respuesta == 'y':
                    self.Nodoactual = yesNode
                else: 
                    self.Nodoactual = noNode
                self.pregunta = self.Nodoactual[0]

        #el siguiente return es obligatorio
        return super(ExpertoView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kargs):
        """ Use this to add extra context """
        context = super(ExpertoView, self).get_context_data(**kargs)
        context["pregunta"] = self.pregunta
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look a bit more on how the framework and HTTP works.

First, HTTP is stateless, it doesn't remember the state of the last request. The "hack" to remember what you did last summer, I meant request, is to use sessions.

Secondly, for every HTTP request Django is going to instantiate a new `ExpertoView`. So even if you update the self.Nodoactual attribute, the next request (which doesn't know nothing about the last request) is going to start with `self.arbol`. Here is where you should use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) in your view.

```
        # maybe something like this?
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form_data = form.cleaned_data
            respuesta = form_data.get('campo')
            if respuesta == 'y':
                self.requests.session['Nodoactual'] = yesNode
            else: 
                self.requests.session['Nodoactual'] = noNode
            self.pregunta = self.Nodoactual[0]
```

Godspeed.